# Table cells appear empty

Tags: ios

I'm having a problem with populating tables. 
I  created a custom view and in the view I created a tableview. The code for the `UIView` subclass is given below . The table appears and all the delegates are called.

24 cells are created as per the delegate and they appear but the text or any other cell contents don't appear. I'm not able to change any cell property including cell background color.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andCellHeight:(CGFloat)cellh{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){

        [self initTimeArray];
        [self initTable];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) initTable{
    timeLine = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height )];
    timeLine.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
   timeLine.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    timeLine.rowHeight = cellHeight;
    timeLine.delegate =self;
    timeLine.dataSource = self;
    [self addSubview:timeLine];
}


-  (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TimeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    }


    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 2)];
    [lineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
   // [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
    UILabel *time = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 40 , 40)];
    time.text = @"Test text";
    time.textColor = [ UIColor  redColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Another test Text";
    [time setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:time];

    return cell;

}
-(void) initTimeArray
{
    timeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12 PM", @"11 PM" ,
                 @"10 PM", @"9 PM", @"8 PM" , @"7 PM" ,
                 @"6 PM", @"5 PM", @"4 PM" , @"3 PM" ,
                 @"2 PM", @"1 PM",   @"12 PM", @"11 AM" ,
                 @"10 AM", @"9 AM", @"8 AM" , @"7 AM" ,
                 @"6 AM", @"5 AM", @"4 AM" , @"3 AM",
                 @"2 AM", @"1 AM" , @"12 AM", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 24;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: are you not able to set text in tableView cell?

Comment: I found the issue. `cellHeight` was `nil` , I gave it a valid value and everything worked.

Comment: Why are you using the cellIdentifier just to create a new cell but not for reusing a cell?
`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];`

Comment: I am using it :) in this particular code, I was testing something without reuse enabled

Comment: @Aneesh could you please add your comment as an answer and accept it so that others can benefit from it.